# Data Import not importing full amount - only existing susbcribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, import, subscriber

We get files placed on our FTP to use as data extensions for email campaigns. I have a custom automation with 4 steps (using a combination of query activities, ampscript and SSJS):

1. Import File to Media_Master
2. Add a record of this happening to Media_Log (using the name of the file as a job reference (Job_Ref) and a datestamp)
3. Create a Data Extension by finding the latest Job_Ref on the Media_Log and using this as the name
4. Updating a query's target data extension to this data extension and updating the definition to 'SELECT * FROM Media_Master WHERE Job_Ref = 'Job_Ref_Here' and then running it

We recently noticed that the import is not importing the full amount of records on the data extension. When we do a manual import with the same file, it works and we get the full amount. However, when we run it via this automation, we always lose records, and I'm pretty sure it's 'new subscribers' that it's not recognising. Any ideas why or how my automation could be ignoring new subscribers, or at least not adding them to the data extension?

Comment: What is the import method you have selected in your import activity? (Update only, Add only, Add and Update, Overwrite) I would also verify that Job_Ref is correctly mapped on your import activity.

Comment: Also, on a semi related note, how are you getting the name of the file? SFMC has told me it is impossible for the user to access the file name from an import unless it is also stored inside the file being uploaded.

Comment: @Gortonington I'm using an Add and Update, but the primary key is set as a combination of email_address and job_ref, so if an email address appears on more than one job (which they do) they won't overwrite their existing record (is this correct?) and to get the name of the file, I'm appending everyone to the _Master and _Log data extensions, then run a CreateDE ampscript block to create it using the latest entry in the Log as the name, then update a query with the same name to find the target DE.

Comment: hmm. By manually do you mean import via wizard, or running the import activity manually?  It sounds like something is not working correctly in the import activity.

Comment: The import is working correctly - it's importing every record to the _Master data extension. But then when I run a query to select all with that job number, and place it on a newly created sendable data extension, it doesn't find everyone.

Comment: @TCassa do you delete contacts via REST API? If you do, they are automatically removed from sendable Data Extension based on SubscriberKey value.

Comment: OK I've found the root of the problem - it's copying them from the _Master which is a non-sendable DE to a sendable DE. I tested it by trying to copy them to a non-sendable DE with the same query and it worked.